# How to map the API publisher query parameter values to the Backend URL resource path in WSO2 API M

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I need to map the API publisher query parameter values to backend URL resource path. I have the API publisher URL be like

"https://102.20.10.3:8245/srno/v1.0/studentRecordNo?user_id=test29"

and the Backend URL like

"http://localhost:8280/services/getStudRecNo.HTTPEndpoint/getsrno/{uri.var.user_id}"

When i execute in swagger , i am getting error like below

```
{
  "Fault": {
    "Code": "",
    "Reason": "DS Code: VALIDATION_ERROR\nNested Exception:-\njavax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Code: VALIDATION_ERROR\nSource Data Service:-\nName: getStudRecNo\nLocation: \\getStudRecNo.dbs\nDescription: get student unique id\r                                \r                                \r                                \nDefault Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice\nCurrent Request Name: _getgetsrno_user_id\nCurrent Params: {user_id={studentRecordNo,test29}}\nNested Exception:-\nScalar type expected\nField Name: user_id\nField Value: {studentRecordNo,test29}\n\n",
    "Detail": ""
  }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: While publishing select path param instead of qury param as api mgmt will take dynamically that one.

Comment: Thanks , currently using path param only.